# Google Map Dimensions in JQuery Mobile

Tags: google-maps, html, jquery-mobile, google-maps-api-3

I'm using Google Maps in my JQuery Mobile application, However as you see in the screenshot below, the map is showing but part of it is off the screen (on the right) but it is okay on the left.

How can I show the right part like the left part ? and having a margin that works on all mobiles, so I don't want fixed values.

This happens in web browser too, not only mobile.

code used :

```
<!-- Home Page -->
<div id="home" data-role="page" data-fullscreen="true">
    <div data-role="content">
        <div id="map_canvas" style="height:97%; width: 97%; position: absolute"></div>
```

[image: mobile screen]

Comment: What is the parent node of the map_canvas div, and what size does it have? Also, why do you use position: absolute?

Comment: I updated the code. Because only 'absolute' shows the map.

Comment: So, the map_canvas has a width that is 97% of what?